# How do I filter an array based on object's property with multiple OR statements

Tags: arrays, swift

The question was difficult to put into words, but here is my situation. I have several Monster objects in an array called `monsters`. Each monster has a `name` property which is a String.
I have a second array called `monsterNames`, which contains several monster names (as Strings).

I want to be able to filter all the monster objects in `monsters` array based on whether the individual monster object's name property appears in the `monsterNames` array.

I have been looking at solutions so far I have only found solutions that filter based on a single condition, which allows me to only filter based on a single monster name in the `monsterNames` array. Can anybody help me find an efficient solution to this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
let monsters: [Monster] = ...

let monsterNames: [String] = ...

let filteredMonsters = monsters.filter { monsterNames.contains($0.name) }
```

This doesn't perform all that well, since it will go over the `names` array up to `n` times for each monster, but if your `names` arrays is small, this won't be a problem.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to remove the ones that matches any monsterName so I think he wants `monsters.filter {!monsterNames.contains($0.name) }`