# how to remove common elements from one array by comparing it with another array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a class

```
class CardImage {
var imageName: String?
var image : UIImage?
var is_saved = false
}
```

I have two arrays

```
var imagesToBeDeleted = [String]()
var cardImages = [CardImage]()
```

I want to delete elements from `cardImages` that has property `imageName` similar to the elements present in `imagesToBeDeleted`.

EXTRA DETAIL: from the names of both arrays you can figure out that `imagesToBeDeleted` will be subset of `imageName` property of `cardImages` array.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339431/how-do-i-filter-an-array-based-on-objects-property-with-multiple-or-statements, which is quite similar. You only have to negate the condition.

Comment: Why don't you prefer <set> ?

Comment: The link solved my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to use `filter` on `cardImages`, check if the name of the current card is present in the `imagesToBeDeleted` array or not and only keep the elements of `cardImages` that are not present in the other array.

`cardImages = cardImages.filter{!imagesToBeDeleted.contains($0.imageName)}`